# Any way to interpret pstree?

Tags: character-encoding, unicode

```
-bash-3.2$ pstree 29838
RBcron.shâââjavaâââ15*[{java}]

-bash-3.2$ pstree 24423
bashââ¬âRBcron.shâââjavaâââ15*[{java}]
  ââvim
-bash-3.2$
```

Any way to interpret this? Why would this happen?

Comment: consider "âââ" as "---", So there are 15 threads named java in a process java whose parent is RBcron.sh. The second line is 15 threads named java in a process java whose parent in RBcron.sh whose parent is bash.

Comment: Try `LANG=C pstree` or `pstree -A`

Comment: Understood, but what made this happen?

Comment: I do not understand your question. Please elaborate.

Comment: It meant, why it was not in the readable format..

Comment: The output is not readable because , your locale is messed up, I think. Doing `LANG=C pstree` or `pstree -A´ (using ascii output) should work, is it working?

Comment: The terminal emulator assumes a different encoding compared to the output. Both should be set to utf-8, there is no reason to use any other encoding but ascii and utf-8, the rest just make things completely unportable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output is garbled because of locale(current language) setting. Doing `LANG=C` disables the localization (sets it to default language).

So the solutions to your problem is either disable localization and do

```
    $ LANG=C psteree
```

or ask pstree to print ascii characaters by

```
   $ pstree -A
```